# 'BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF' not declared error while buiding R Studio on ppc64le

Tags: rstudio

I could use some help here.

I encountered the following "'BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF' was not declared in this scope" error whiling trying to build R Studio on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, ppc64le.

Googling did not produced much help.  Can someone help me out, pls ?

The rstudio version is the lastest one from the github, and boost stuff was installed both from apt repository and from running dependencies/common/install-boost script, which is included in rstudio source code.

$ wget https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/archive/master.zip

> ~/files/rstudio-master/build$ cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ~/files/rstudio-master/build$ make all ...
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 5 minutes 50 seconds [  0%] Built target
>   gwt_build [  1%] Building CXX object
>   src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/file_lock/FileLock.cpp.o In
>   file included from
>   /opt/rstudio-tools/boost/boost_1_50_0/include/boost/asio/ip/detail/endpoint.hpp:138:0,
>                    from /opt/rstudio-tools/boost/boost_1_50_0/include/boost/asio/ip/basic_endpoint.hpp:20,
>                    from /opt/rstudio-tools/boost/boost_1_50_0/include/boost/asio.hpp:53,
>                    from /home/u0017496/files/rstudio-master/src/cpp/core/include/core/FileLock.hpp:28,
>                    from /home/u0017496/files/rstudio-master/src/cpp/core/file_lock/FileLock.cpp:16:
>   /usr/include/boost/asio/ip/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp: In constructor
>   'boost::asio::ip::detail::endpoint::endpoint()':
>   /usr/include/boost/asio/ip/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp:38:50: error:
>   'BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF' was not declared in this scope
>   data_.v4.sin_family = BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF(AF_INET);
>                                                     ^ /usr/include/boost/asio/ip/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp: In constructor
>   'boost::asio::ip::detail::endpoint::endpoint(int, short unsigned
>   int)': /usr/include/boost/asio/ip/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp:47:42:
>   error: 'BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF' was not declared in this scope    if
>   (family == BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF(AF_INET))
>                                             ^

...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on Debian Stretch.
It may originate from having boost already installed in another version. After removing the boost version previously installed via apt and deleting /opt/rstudio-tools, then running the install-dependencies script again, the error was gone.

(To be fair however, I should add that now I get errors related to boost and openssl.)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this, the problem that I found was that I had run one of the build steps with `sudo`. This meant that some temporary files were locked, because they belong to root.

Solution

```
sudo rm bin.v2 -rf  
./b2 (build as normal again)
```